# Set Conditional IconSets in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

When adding conditional formatting to a sheet using c#
How do I set the IconSet being used?
Below isn't currently working. It gives me a set of default icons but not the ones I want.

```
Excel.IconSetCondition cfIconSet =
    (Excel.IconSetCondition)excelWorksheet.get_Range(cellNumber, cellNumber)
      .FormatConditions
      .AddIconSetCondition();
cfIconSet.IconSet = Excel.XlIconSet.xl3Flags;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

```
cfIconSet.IconSet = cfIconSet.IconSet(Excel.XlIconSet.xl3Flags);
```